# pad print line with white space C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

In C++ I am using **unsigned char** pointers to hold byte arrays so that I can fit 8 bit color codes in each element for a print line.

I have one array holding data, and one array holding white space, and I am using for loops to populate a third array so that the data is at the beginning and white space is at the end.

When the pointer is created, as I monitor memory at runtime, all elements have a default value of `0xCD`, which is magenta on color chart. I use a for loop to populate the bytes I want with 0x00, but it will not write over the default array value of the third array.

So, I am stuck with my printer printing magenta instead of white space. Yet I can write over that array just fine with just the data. But not with the whitespace. Im unsure what is the reason for that. Can anyone give me any insight? Here is my code...

```
PrintLine(unsigned char* pbData, unsigned long ulDataSize, UINT xoffset)
{ 
   if (xoffset > 0) 
   {  //create pointer to byte array for xoffset 
      unsigned char* offsetData; 
      offsetData = new unsigned char[(xoffset / 8)]; //x offset is divided by 8 
      //to convert pixels to bytes
      //create pointer to byte array to hold image data and offset data
      unsigned char* finalData;
      finalData = new unsigned char[ulDataSize + (xoffset / 8)];
      //begin final data with image data passed into the function
     for (int count = 0; count < ulDataSize; count++)
     {
         finalData[count] = pbData[count];
     }

     //populate offset data with blank bytes
     for (int count = 0; count < (xoffset / 8); count++)
     {
         offsetData[count] = 0x00;
     }

     //add blank data for offset to finalData
     int position = 0;
     for (int count = ulDataSize; count < ulDataSize + (xoffset / 8);count++)
     {
         finalData[ulDataSize] = offsetData[position];//also tried =0x00
         position++;
     }
     //Send data to printer.
     if (!(Write(finalData, ulDataSize + (xoffset / 8)))
     {       
         return FALSE;
     }
    return TRUE;
  }
}
```

Comment: what does `(xoffset / 8)` do when `(xoffset % 8) != 0`? Also don't forget to `delete` anything you've `new`'d ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance your code don't have errors, but I see something that looks suspicious. I'm talking about the line:

```
finalData[ulDataSize] = offsetData[position]; //also tried =0x00
```

I think what you want is:

```
finalData[count] = offsetData[position];//also tried =0x00
```

On the other hand you could write your loop like this:

```
for (int count = 0; count < (xoffset / 8); count++)
{
    finalData[ulDataSize + count] = offsetData[count];
}
```

Making the code much more readable.

Comment: The reason I am not starting at the beginning of finalData is because i want the white space to be at the end of the array. That is why my count is the size of the actual image data. So I will start at the end of the image data and count up to the end of the image data and white space data combined

Comment: @NathanielSmith: That makes the loop useless, though, because you're writing over the same spot many times.

Comment: @NathanielSmith, yes but inside the loop `ulDataSize` reamins the same, so you're setting `0x00` to the same position every time, you need to use `count` for moving around `finalData`.